# python: import another project module named same with a local module

Tags: python, import

I have two python projects. The first one is a django project located at `/path/to/project1/` and has below file structure:

```
project1/
 |- policy/
 |--- models.py
```

And I have another project, say `project2`. Within this project, I'd like to import the some definition from `project1.policy.models`. e.g.

```
 sys.path.append('/path/to/project1/')
 from policy.models import SomeModel
```

However, the issue is, in project2, there's also an directory named `policy`, which result in an ImportError. I cannot rename either directory name of `policy`.
I do try absolute import, i.e. `from __future__ import absolute_import` but doesn't work.

BTW, my python version is 2.6.1

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to achieve your goal:

```
 project1/
     __init__.py
     policy/
         __init__.py
         models.py (contains SomeModels)

 project2/
     test_file.py
     policy/
         __init__.py
```

Above is your directory structure. Added is the **_*init*_.py** under **project1/** so that you can import project1. Now in the test_file.py, you can do the following to achieve your goal:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/project1/')
from project1.policy.models import SomeModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your setup so you can do this:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/')
from project1.policy.models import SomeModel
from project2.policy.models import SomeOtherModel
```

Just adding an empty `__init__.py` in `/path/to/project1` and `/path/to/project2` will do.