# Python import package from different project

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a package from a different project, but it's not recognising the project that I'm trying to import from. I've looked at various answers to this question (including [python: import another project module named same with a local module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786563/python-import-another-project-module-named-same-with-a-local-module)).

My project structure looks like this:

```
Project1
 - __init__.py
 - foo_directory
  - foo.py
  - __init__.py


Project2
 - __init__.py
 -bar_directory
  - bar.py
  - __init__.py
```

In bar.py I'm trying to do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/Project2')

from Project1.foo_directory import foo.py
```

I can't work out why it's not recognising Project1 when I try to do an import?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30625670/4954037

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Python modules from different working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046628/importing-python-modules-from-different-working-directory)

Answer (score 5):

You should create two packages, `Project1` and `Project2` (note the [`setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html))

```
Project1
 - setup.py
 - Project1
  - __init__.py
  - foo_directory
   - foo.py
   - __init__.py
```

and

```
Project2
 - setup.py
 - Project2
  - __init__.py
  - bar_directory
   - bar.py
   - __init__.py
```

then install them

```
pip install -e Project1/
pip install -e Project2/
```

And then you can simply do

```
from Project1.foo_directory import foo
```

The obvious advantage: Package2 depends on Package1 but *doesn't need to know where it was installed*. Managing all the import paths is done by `pip` and the environment you're in (hopefully a virtualenv).

Comment: if i don't put Project2 inside Project 1, i get `.. should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+` , local package must be inside the parent package to install?

Comment: @TomSawyer please open a new question

Answer (score 1):

Based on the advice Maresh gave me, I did the following (I'm using Windows, which is why I couldn't follow his answer exactly):

In PyCharm: File > Settings > Project: Project1 > Project Structure.
  - Add Content Root (add the location for Project2).
  - Apply and OK

Then in bar.py I was able to import files from Project2

Answer (score 0):

2 Solutions:

1- Use the PYTHONPATH environoment variable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath) for more details

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$(PYTHONPATH):/path/to/project1
```

2 - Create a setup.py for your projects so you can install them, thus import them>

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html

Note: Messing with the sys.path from within app is not a recommanded solution as it is not really robust not crossplatform.

Answer (score 0):

### A workaround for Project2's `bar.py` to import Project1's `foo.py`

Adopted from a workaround I've been using myself.

**Important:** For this workaround to work you may need to disable any format-on-save feature, specifically because of the rule “E402 - Fix module level import not at top of file”

### a) either with a hardcoded absolute path to Project1:

(don't forget an absolute path starts with a leading slash)

`bar.py`:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath('/abs/path/Project1')
)
from Project1.foo_directory import foo as f
```

### b) or with a relative path from `bar.py` location to Project1, converted programmatically to an absolute path:

`bar.py`:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__),
            '../../Project1'
        )
    )
)
from Project1.foo_directory import foo as f
```