# Python - Import Classes from different Projects

Tags: python, import, python-import

First off all: Sorry - I know that there already exist several questions which concern issues with the python import mechanism. However after hours of searching through SO I still couldn't find a sufficent answer for me.

## Problem

I've got two independent Python projects hosted on my GitLab Server.
Let's call them **foo** and **foo-Tester**. 
As the name implies, **foo-Tester** is a automatic Tester for the **foo**-Project.

**foo** has the following structure:

```
-foo
  - __init__.py
  - fooClass.py
  -bar
     - __init__.py
     - barClass.py
  -foobar
     - __init__.py
     - foobarClass.py
   etc.
```

The classes import each other via relativ imports.

For sake of this example the **foo-Tester** Project just contains:

```
- foo-Tester
   - __init__.py
   - tester.py
```

While the *tester.py* just contains:

```
from foo.fooClass import fooClass
myfoo = fooClass()
```

Both Projects reside next to each other on the file-system:

```
- some-folder
   - foo
   - foo-Tester
```

So my question is: What is the best approach/best-practice to import the *fooClass* from **foo** into *tester.py* from the **foo-Tester**-Project?

## What I've tried

#### Using setup.py

Some Answers (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071394/6033621) suggest using **setup.py**. As far as I understand this approach, one would need to install the **foo**-Project each time it is changed - am I correct?
This wouldn't be a good solution for us as the Project is under heavy development with many changes a day.

#### Appending to system-path

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509415/6033621) answer suggest adding the **foo** project path to the system path. And running the script with the `-m` Flag

Two concerns about this approach:

- it seems a bit hacky to modify the systempaths
- it seems like this doesn't work with the relative imports from the **foo** project as it always throws an `relative imports not allowed`-Error.

I am using Python 3.6.
So what would be the best approach for the described problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to do anything. Since both folders contain `__init__.py` files, they are packages; so `from foo.fooClass import fooClass` should work fine. Note, to import anything from foo-Tester you should change its name to a valid Python identifier, eg `foo_tester`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the thread out here: [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) , this is the way how you can import modules from parent (or any other) folder.

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 

import mymodule
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However this seems to me like a hacky workaround as well. Isn't there a more simple/ straight forward approach to this general problem?